# Is there a way to make a query hold all of the rows associated with another single row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

This is a simplified version of my tables:

#### Images

```
image_id       user_id     image_path   
-------------------------------------
1              1           TEXT        
2              2           TEXT
```

#### Votes

```
vote_id           image_id       user_id 
-----------------------------------------
1                 1              1       
2                 1              2       
3                 2              1     
4                 1              3       
5                 1              4
```

As you can see, there are 4 votes associated with image #1.

I currently have the following code:

```
SELECT images.*, votes.*
FROM images
LEFT JOIN votes
ON images.image_id = votes.vote_id           
GROUP BY images.image_id;
```

What this does is basically return every single image joined with how many times such image was voted up. This IS the desired action, however... It only returns one vote, it does not return all of the votes associated with the image.

**Why do I need all of the votes?** In my loop, I want to check if a user has already voted on the image, and if he has already voted, then do not show the vote button. Since my query is only returning one vote out of the many associated with an image, there is no way for me to know what other users already voted.

**Is there a way to make the query hold all of the votes associated with the image while only returning one image?**

Thank you and I hope this made sense.

Comment: You mention tables images and votes... but your query references tables add_time and add_vote?

Comment: Please check your `ON` condition. Shouldn't it be `votes.image_id`?

Comment: Please provide the desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: Does this query work ? You are selecting all columns (images.*, votes.*) and grouping by as well - It should be a syntax error.

Comment: @PM77-1 the problem is that my desired output would contain all of the votes in an array-like kind of thing. Since I only want to output one image based on it's ID, but also output **all** of the image's votes, all in one single join.

Comment: @SuyashKhandwe, yes. It works. It gives me all of the images by image_id **ONCE**.

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all the user ids who votes in a list, using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT i.*, group_concat(v.user_id)
FROM images i LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON i.image_id = v.vote_id           
GROUP BY i.image_id;
```

Comment: That's something new. Thank you! How would I check if the user_id exists within the group_concat? If possible, can you guide me the right way using PHP?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out in my own way by exploding it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the second condition in your on clause based on `user_id`

```
SELECT images.*, votes.*
FROM images
LEFT JOIN votes
ON images.image_id = votes.image_id  AND votes.`user_id`=1 ;
```

Then fetch results from query and check if user id is not null then show button else do not show

[**See 3 users voted images**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c29d/2)

```
if(userid is null){
your vote button
}else{
already voted
}
```